# Index error due to the for-loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, index-error

As I am new to python programming. I have a problem in the for loop with index error. I have gone through the suggestions that you have given me. My problem is that in the for loop...
I didn't get any error with this code below...

```
for i in range(0,1):
```

But I have obtained an error if the limit exceeds for example (0,3)

```
for i in range(0,3):
```

The error is

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I have tried to clear out this error and I am not sure that why this error occurs in the for loop if the limits exceed 1.

This is my code:

```
m=['paketone4000.dump.xlsx','paketone8000.dump.xlsx','paketone12000.dump.xlsx']
fig_name=['j4000','e8000','e12000']

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,6)) ##to obtain figure and dimensions of graph

for i in range(0,3):


    #ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d') ## to have a broad view of figure
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1], projection='3d')

    #plot planes
    p = Rectangle((0,-0.7), 4.5,1.4, color="lightgrey", alpha=0.2) #plots the background frame
    ax.add_patch(p)

    art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0, zdir="z")

    j=pd.read_excel(m[i])  ##to read the excel file format
    X=j['x'] ## to import the variable on to axes from data set
    Y=j['y']
    Z=j['z']
    #ax.scatter(X,Y,Z,c='g', marker='o') ## to specify the color and shape of point(marker) of the frame

    a=j['x']##import centre of mass from excel file format
    b=j['y']
    c=j['z']

    q1=j['q1'], ##attaining quaternons from excel file format. (comma(,) transformed series to tuple)
    q2=j['q2'],
    q3=j['q3'],
    q4=j['q4'],

    m,n,o,p=np.array([q1,q2,q3,q4]) ## assigning quaternions to variables had converted tuple to float
    Rot_Mat=QtoR(m,n,o,p)

    #cuboid initialising parameters
    center = [a[0], b[0], c[0]] ##centre of the body
    length = 0.3 ##defining length, breadth, height
    width = 0.4
    height = 0.1
    side = np.zeros((8,3))  ###This numpy vector will be used to store the position of the sides

    #rotate the axes and update
    for angle in range(0, 360):
        ax.view_init(90, angle)

    cuboid(center, (length, width, height)) #to execute the defined cuboid

    plt.savefig(fig_name[i])
    plt.clf()
print("\nq1=",m,"q2=",n,"q3=",o,"q4=",p)
print('\nRotation Matrix=',Rot_Mat)
print ("\nCenter = \n",center)
```

My expected result is that I want to remove the error that was obtained and I am interested in to know why that error occurred when end limit is greater than one.

Comment: `m` only has three elements at indexes `0` , `1`, and `2`, what do you expect `m[4]` to be when you use `j=pd.read_excel(m[a])` and `a` is `4`?

Comment: even for `a in range(1)` this `center = [a[0], b[0], c[0]]` throw `TypeError`

Comment: Yes, i have changed  `for i in range(0,3):` with center `center = [a[i],b[i],c[i]]` even though throughs `index error`

Comment: is `a`, `b` or `c` a list/tuple?

Comment: if i want the `m[4]` then i will change the range of for-loop as `for i in range (0,5):`. Is this the answer that you are expecting or anything else?

Comment: `a`,`b`,`c` are neither list/tuple. The type is in series. I don't think that the error is due to that because i am obtaining the error over here `j=pd.read_excel(m[a])`.

Comment: You're overwriting your `m` variable from the top of the file with `m,n,o,p=np.array([q1,q2,q3,q4])`.

Comment: This may be the case. I have edited `m` to `packet` as you can see now in the code. At this point, i am obtaining an error `center = [a[i], b[i], c[i]] ##centre of the body

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 1`

Comment: Please don't change the code in your question in such a way that it changes the source of your error. We can't answer a moving target like that, and you've invalidated the existing answers. If you have a new issue, ask a new question (perhaps linking back to this one).

Comment: Ok, Thank you i will now keep the old version.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the name `m` for two different variables in your code. At the top of the file you use it to create a list of filenames, which you read in the loop. But later in the loop, you reassign it with this line:

```
m,n,o,p=np.array([q1,q2,q3,q4])
```

That causes the error when you try to read later files, as the new `m` value doesn't contain what the code expects (and may not be the expected size).

You should use two different variable names. This kind of issue suggest that it might be a good idea to use longer, more descriptive variable name, as you are a lot less likely to have this kind of random namespace collision with names like `filenames` and `first_quaternion` (or whatever).

I'd also suggest using `range(len(m))` so that if you change the size of the list at some future time, you won't need to remember to also change the hard-coded range size.

Comment: Ya, This may be the case. I have edited m to packet as you can see now in the code. At this point, i am obtaining an error `center = [a[i], b[i], c[i]] ##centre of the body File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item KeyError: 1 –`

Answer (score 0):

An [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NktK.png) for this code execution. How about you try replacing

```py
for i in range(0, 5):
```

with

```py
for i in range(len(m)):
```

EDIT:
Does this work?

```py
m=['paketone4000.dump.xlsx','paketone8000.dump.xlsx','paketone12000.dump.xlsx']
fig_name=['j4000','e8000','e12000']

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,6)) ##to obtain figure and dimensions of graph

for index, i in enumerate(m):


    #ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d') ## to have a broad view of figure
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1], projection='3d')

    #plot planes
    p = Rectangle((0,-0.7), 4.5,1.4, color="lightgrey", alpha=0.2) #plots the background frame
    ax.add_patch(p)

    art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0, zdir="z")

    j=pd.read_excel(i)  ##to read the excel file format
    X=j['x'] ## to import the variable on to axes from data set
    Y=j['y']
    Z=j['z']
    #ax.scatter(X,Y,Z,c='g', marker='o') ## to specify the color and shape of point(marker) of the frame

    a=j['x']##import centre of mass from excel file format
    b=j['y']
    c=j['z']

    q1=j['q1'], ##attaining quaternons from excel file format. (comma(,) transformed series to tuple)
    q2=j['q2'],
    q3=j['q3'],
    q4=j['q4'],

    m2,n,o,p=np.array([q1,q2,q3,q4]) ## assigning quaternions to variables had converted tuple to float
    Rot_Mat=QtoR(m2,n,o,p)

    #cuboid initialising parameters
    center = [a[0], b[0], c[0]] ##centre of the body
    length = 0.3 ##defining length, breadth, height
    width = 0.4
    height = 0.1
    side = np.zeros((8,3))  ###This numpy vector will be used to store the position of the sides

    #rotate the axes and update
    for angle in range(0, 360):
        ax.view_init(90, angle)

    cuboid(center, (length, width, height)) #to execute the defined cuboid
    amount_of_files_to_rename=index
    new_names = [i*1000 for i in range(4*amount_of_files_to_rename)[::4]]
    for i in new_names:
        plt.savefig('packetone {}.jpg'.format(i))

    #plt.savefig(fig_name[b])
    #plt.clf()       
print("\nq1=",m2,"q2=",n,"q3=",o,"q4=",p)
print('\nRotation Matrix=',Rot_Mat)
print ("\nCenter = \n",center)
```

Comment: sorry to say, even though the same error  `File "D:/Thesis/Excel/New1-all.py", line 143, in <module>
    j=pd.read_excel(m[i])  ##to read the excel file format

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`. Any other suggestion where the mistake is going on.

Comment: maybe it's a problem with your exel?

Comment: If that is the case then i shouldn't get the image for the first file of excel. In this i am obtaining image for `m[0]`

Comment: The error is at....`File "D:/Thesis/Excel/New1-all.py", line 162, in <module>
    center = [a[index], b[index], c[index]] ##centre of the body`                       with                                                                                                                 
`File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

KeyError: 1`. I have changed the line from your code to this `plt.savefig(fig_name[index])
 plt.clf()`

Comment: Any other suggestion to this question my dear?

Comment: i edited that line, try it now, it seems to me that `a`, `b` and `c` are lists/tuples with `len=1`

Comment: Before that only i have also seen that you have placed the `a[index]` in `center` of which i wanted to say you. Sorry, i have just making attempts and then finalised before you have done. Now, i am writing to give you a response for your valuable time.

Comment: `m=['paketone4000.dump.xlsx','paketone8000.dump.xlsx','paketone1400000.dump.xlsx']
fig_name=['i4000','i8000','i12000']` As you can see in the code m, fig_name. If i want to keep these files in one folder and the image names should be automatic named then how can i do this? The execution must be one file after other as the above code is executed

Comment: i honestly don't understand what you are trying to achieve, can you elaborate on what you want from your code?

Comment: According to my code an excel file can create an image. So, rather than giving file names in `m` and image names in `fig_name`. I want import one after other excel file from a folder and then it has to create its own image name for the particular excel file which has to be saved in other folder.

Comment: do you have a picture per excel file, or `n` number of pictures per excel file?

Comment: i have created a code for excel files `import re
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = "C:/Nutakki/All_set/excel files/episode0/"
m = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
pattern = re.compile(r"\d+")
m = sorted(m, key = lambda m :  int(pattern.findall(m)[0]) )
print(m)` rather than giving names as a list. In the same manner the image should be saved with different names.

Comment: if you don't care about the image name, just make it random, example: 
`import random
new_name = random.randint(0, 9999999)`

Comment: what is b in code line ` plt.savefig(fig_name[b])` where did you assigned `b`?

Comment: Instead of  this ``plt.savefig(fig_name[b])``, i have added this ``plt.savefig(fig_name[index])``. But the problem is that it gives index 350 instead of 351 when you ``print(index)``.

Comment: list's index starts with 0 and ends with `len(list)-1`

Comment: ok, Thank you. Let me see. what about previous question in comment.

Comment: for the names you can try something like this: `new_names = [i for i in range(4000*amount_of_files)[::4000]]`

Comment: I haven't understood your recent comment. I have tried like this ``plt.savefig('packetone {0}.jpg'.format(index))`` which worked well but it attains names as follow: `packetone 0.jpg, packetone 1.jpg, packetone 2.jpg......` but i required like this format `packetone 0.jpg, packetone 4000.jpg, packetone 8000.jpg,....` What have to be changes in my code line?

Comment: `new_names = [i*1000 for i in range(4*amount_of_files_to_rename)[::4]]` <- this generates a list of new names(0, 4000, 8000 and so on) based on the ` amount_of_files_to_rename` how you use it is on you :), but i recommend you do it in a new(separate) `for` loop, something like this: `for i in new_names: plt.savefig('packetone {}.jpg'.format(i))`

Comment: Ya, it works good. If i have a doubt then i will contact you. Now the images are saved in same folder but I am unable to save this in other folder.

Comment: ``new_names = [i*1000 for i in range(4*amount_of_files_to_rename)[::4]]``. Can you explain what does `4` represents?

Comment: in the case of `new_names = [i*1000 for i in range(4*amount_of_files_to_rename)[::4]]`, `[::4]` is the step, for more info [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).

Comment: I have added these code lines in your code ``amount_of_files_to_rename=index
    new_names = [i*1000 for i in range(4*amount_of_files_to_rename)[::4]]
    for i in new_names:
        plt.savefig('packetone {}.jpg'.format(i))``  Is that correct? But the plot obtaining is the last image to all the files.

Comment: is the amount of pictures per `.xlsx` file fixed, or different every time?

Comment: It was fixed every time. In the recent comment code. I am obtaining ``.xlsx`` file name to the image file name with perfect match but all the images that are formed are for the last ``.xlsx`` file.

Comment: it's because you save images with the same names for every `.xlsx` file, i recommend you do this:  change `for i in new_names:
        plt.savefig('packetone {}.jpg'.format(i))` to this `for j in new_names:
        plt.savefig('packetone {} {}.jpg'.format(index, j))`, also what is the amount of images in your `.xlsx` files?

Comment: shall i add the code that you have suggested below this for loop ``for index, i in enumerate(m):`` or outside it?

Comment: I want to obtain ``paketone0, paketone4000, paketone8000....`` for the excel files ``paketone0.dump, paketone4000.dump, paketone8000.dump...`` but obtaining like this ``paketone0, paketone1, paketone2....`` for the suggested code in the latest comment.....

Comment: How to save this images in other folder?

Comment: to save files in a different folder you need to pass not just a name(like `plt.savefig('filename')`) but a full path, relative or absolute, example: `plt.savefig('path/to/your/file/and/name.jpg')`. and for the naming issue... you can try using the name of your `.xlsx` files, example: `plt.savefig(string_with_a_single_xlsx_file_name.split('.', 1)[0]+'.jpg')`. also sorry for the delay, hope this helps.